# Add centralized logging to kubernetes cluster that use systemd

Tags: logging, kubernetes, fluentd

I'm trying to add centralized logging to my kubernetes cluster using EFK. I found out that my logs from pods that are written to system out are stored in journald in my master node. But I want to store those logs in elasticsearch.

Can I change docker config to redirect logs to var logs? I try to avoid to log from my pods in custom location.

Or can I intercept the logs from journald using fluentd or anything else?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like your solution: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-elasticsearch-kibana/

Answer (score 1):

Please try this [link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/shipping-kubernetes-logs-to-elasticsearch-with-filebeat)

The basic idea is to run Filebeat as a daemonset, which will collect and ship logs from containers and push to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I understand correctly from the yaml file Filebeat reads logs from "/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log" and my problem is that docker doesn’t write to files, it writes to journald. My question is how can I modify docker/kubernetes to log to files or how can I capture logs from journald?

Comment: There are 2 options , 1. You can check this [link](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) to change the default docker logging back to json-log , this is from where filebeat then picks up and ships the log to Elasticsearch . 2. Use a [Journalbeat](https://github.com/mheese/journalbeat) a community beat created specifically to ship logs from journald to Elasticsearch. If you do not have any specific reason to ship your docker logs to journald , i believe 1st option might be an easier approach

Comment: I tried to add in daemon.json "log-driver": "json-file", but then docker failed to start "Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details." I can figure out what is the problem..

Comment: Please check detail logs from journalctl -xeu docker.service , i think there will lot more details there. Also please check if your user has appropriate permissions.Are you running docker as root ?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. You helped me a lot, I figured out what the problem was. I had installed an older version of docker on machines and I installed the latest docker and all works fine.